# Python Black failed to format `print("\n", end='')`

Tags: python, python-black

The error:

```
error: cannot format <filename>.py: Cannot parse: <line-number>:<column-number>: print("\n", end='')
```

Why can't black format this code? If I remove it, Black just fails again at the next point that it encounters a `print` function with `end` in it.

Comment: Are those plain ASCII double-quotes?

Comment: I'm guessing you can't do both `"\n"` and `end=''` in the same `print` function.

Comment: Im guessing the issue is a quote or parenthesis that you left open on a previous line

Comment: @JoranBeasley Looks like you were correct. I had an if statement with no content. Removing that solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

... just to close the question (credits to @Joran Beasley)

Unbalanced parentheses and quotes will lead to this error (that will be reported on further lines if this line is removed).

Be sure to always check that your code is correct: e.g., with Python linters like [`pylint`](https://pylint.org/), [Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) (embedded in VS Code), [`pylama`](https://pypi.org/project/pylama/), ...